# Qt build x86 target from Qt 5.6.3 msvc2015 64bit

Tags: c++, qt, build, qmake

6.3 msvc2015 64bit and I want build my code for x86 target machine, is it possible?
I made manual kit for this but Not work!!
Here is picture of my compiler list and my kit detile

---------> My Compiler list [image: Picture of my compiler list]

-------------> My manual kit detail [image]

### How it's possible to make x86 build .exe file for my 32bit Windows target?

You say I shoud instal Qt 5.6.3 msvc2015 32bit to compile my program for x86 target machine ?

And in my screenshot Qt version shoud be `Qt 5.6.3 msvc2015 32bit`?

Comment: The first compiler in the list is marked `(x86)`. Seems like it should work.

Comment: @bo-persson but its not work i get  fatal error LNK1112: module machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'X86'

Comment: @JesperJuhl You can not use a 64bit library (Qt) in a 32bit application => "is it possible?" No! Note that you can use 64bit _QtCreator_ to build 32bit applications.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the 32-bit version of Qt is installed in the MaintenanceTool. It should then show up in its own kit.

In the screenshot you posted, the kit uses a 64-bit version of Qt, which will not work.

Comment: You say I shoud instal Qt 5.6.3 msvc2015 32bit to compile my program for x86 target machine ? and its not possible with my Qt 5.6.3 msvc2015 64bit version ? and in my screenshot Qt version shoud be Qt 5.6.3 msvc2015 32bit ????

Comment: @shinyboy Indeed, it is not possible.

Comment: @shinyboy You cannot build a 32-bit program that uses 64-bit DLLs. You need to install the 32-bit DLLs of Qt. Also, 5.6 is very old. The latest version is 5.9, and 5.10 is currently in beta. Are you using a recent enough version of the MaintenanceTool? You might be using a very old installation of Qt in general. If you're not sure, I'd recommend uninstalling Qt completely, and then grab the latest online installer/updater from: https://www1.qt.io/download-open-source/

Answer (score 0):

**I solve it** ! Its not possible to compile from x64 host to x86 target ! 
for this shoud Instal version x86 of Qt and use x86 Qt version for build .exe file!